# Passing an option when a Select element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/hL7Lnf3a/3/ - with a `select` dropdown menu of files. When a file is selected from the menu the `.change()` handler is entered. I'd like to let the user somehow tell me when they select a file that instead of loading the file, they want to delete it. This could be by holding down the Shift key, or some other key when they click the entry in the menu, or even by right-clicking instead of left-clicking the entry.  But the browser (I'm running Chrome) doesn't seem to set any of these indications for a `.change` event. That is, I don't see `e.shiftKey` or `e.which` being set in the event object when change event fires.  Does anyone see a way to let the user tell me whether they want to load or delete the file they're selecting?

Thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have another listeners (keyup and keydown) for the shift key.

Use a flag variable to denote whether the key is pressed or not, and then in your change listener simply check for the state of that flag variable.

Something like this:

```
var shiftPressed = false;

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 16)
        shiftPressed = true;
})

$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 16)
        shiftPressed = up;
})
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/hL7Lnf3a/5/ (try changing the select item with and without the shift pressed)

---

A version with a custom drop-down menu: http://jsfiddle.net/g8ptz2eb/11/

Comment: Yes, that's a good step in  the right direction. It's interesting that the state of the Shift key is captured when you click the drop down and can't be changed while the menu is dropped down. You can see that better here ; http://jsfiddle.net/g8ptz2eb/9/.  It would be ideal if the user could press Shift after the menu was down and have the state be seen at .change.

Comment: Yeah, good catch. I'm afraid we're entering the browser's realm here, so the shift key is technically no longer pressed inside the document, but at a higher level - the browser, more accuratelly the browser's select box (notice you can control it with keyboard once it is opened and has focus). To avoid this and possible cross-browser issues in regarding to potentially different implementation of this feature, I strongly suggest you build your own simple dropdown menu and never worry about this again.

Comment: Something like this maybe: http://jsfiddle.net/g8ptz2eb/11/

Comment: That's a much nicer solution than what I have, but this dropdown is buried deep in the project code so changing it to something else now is not easy.  I load the list of files, for example, into the select options with Ajax that calls a php script  that reads the directory on the server. I'm not up to making that all work with a new approach, right now.  But Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I understand, at least you're on the right track now. Not sure how complex your code is, but the difference between a select and this one I gave you is not that big, actually. But you'll see what's the best for you. You're welcome! :)